# How to Run Commands through a already running Java?

Tags: java, php, webserver

I was wondering if it was possible to execute commands from PHP to a Java prompt which is already running?

I have tried the solution listed here: 
[How to run a shell command through PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684742/how-to-run-a-shell-command-through-php-code)

and this provided no functionality

**Let me explain**

The java is running on one screen of the linux server

> sudo apt-get install screen

and running the .jar file through the command line.

I am then running a webserver, which will have an admin accessibility to restricted areas, which will contain scrips to run specific commands through that already running .jar file?

Comment: Can you edit the java file?

Comment: I can edit the java file

Comment: Wait, stop the java file; perform edits then re-run?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement some kind of IPC. The java file listens to a port and receives the commands. Or you can write the commands in a specific file which the java programm reads. I think under linux you can also use shared memory: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php

Comment: How would I go about the IPC?

Comment: IPC just means inter processs communication. There are many ways to implement this. The simplest and most "multiplatform" solution wpould be to just use sockets.

Comment: They both will be running on the same Linux server

Comment: I would use simple TCP sockets. But there are many ways. You even can use some kind of queue. A Database for example which holds all commands and the java process executes them. This would elimiate the problem of concurrent commands.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by sending the command to the screen session. I used this for a minecraft server once.

```
screen -S <sessionname> -X stuff "<command>\r"
```

This would (IIRC) provide the same output as if you where inside the screen, typed the command and pressed enter.
I hope this was what you wanted.